# My ubuntu 20.04 is verly slow on stratup after messing with the swap parition, how do I make it boot faster?

Tags: linux, startup, swap

here's the output when i type dmesg

```
[   45.039698] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   45.039714] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   45.039726] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   82.247013] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

There was another operation causing the dealy up to 200 seconds (snap store), i sloved it by removing snap store, I feel like i will regret this in the future so if there's an alternative to deletion, I'm all ears.
Here's the log from before solving it(i got it from /var/log/syslog.1). it inputs this message repeatedly.

```
Nov  9 13:21:41 myusername kernel: [  195.559737] audit: type=1400 audit(1604924501.888:39): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/globs2" pid=3007 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

All those problems started when messing with my swap partition.
here's some info:
The relevant information for blkid

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="65588ef6-ca0f-4956-b496-e752d63ac471" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="72011e9d-02"
```

the relevant information of /etc/fstab file:
old:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation 
UUID=e75cae65-4915-4d7c-aec1-e509b94fad97 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/44A4EE0FA4EE0372 /mnt/44A4EE0FA4EE0372 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,rw 0 0
```

new:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation (now it's on sda2)
UUID=65588ef6-ca0f-4956-b496-e752d63ac471 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/44A4EE0FA4EE0372 /mnt/44A4EE0FA4EE0372 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,rw 0 0
```

I think i did this correctly, unless there's a piece of information I'm supossed to know but don't.

now rfkill sounds like one of those important things that you shouldn't remove, so my question is:

- Can I remove it?
- Can I make it load at startup faster or at least delay it's loading until my pc is on?
  Thanks in advance!!
  Edit: The requested dmesg output:
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/10-nMb8-P1YfvVIEuONdkyROSJ7Ev-LRB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you post a complete `dmesg` output?

Comment: Edited my question for the full dmesg output

Comment: There's nothing particularly interesting in the log file. Please try using https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improving_performance/Boot_process#Using_systemd-analyze Also it looks like you're using spinning rust (i.e. a normal HDD) - if you could afford it, you could speed up your PC significantly by changing it to an SSD.

Comment: Ouch. But that's not point, ubuntu used to boot faster until i changed the swap partition now it's taking a longer time than before with the same hardware. I tried looking for older logs but they don't exist. So i'm trying to at least making it boot as fast as it was by killing a few things. I read other posts and they told me to type dmesg and look for big time differences and repeated commands. Before posting this I removed snap store which took from 80 sec to 200 sec to boot it didn't tak that long before. Now rfkill takes 40secs to boot, i want to disable it at start up, how can i do that?

Comment: also after reading the link you sent me dmesg | grep SSS has no output so that's not it.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? If more than 4GB temporarily comment out swap entry in fstab with # and see if it makes a difference? That will narrow down if swap is the real issue or not.